# CSS Plugin for Notepad++

Tags: css, plugins, autocomplete, stylesheet, notepad++

I am hoping to find a plugin for Notepad++ that will auto-complete for CSS. Something like TextFX but for CSS. What would be ideal (IMO) is something that completes brackets, but also tosses in a closing ; for every :, any suggestions?

Comment: not really an answer to your question but I prefer Brackets now compared to notepad++.  Also I prefer sublime text 2 to notepad++ too.  Id honestly suggest looking at them if you haven't already.  For CSS Brackets saves you so much time with its realtime rendering of files you modify.  Basically the same as when you edit css in the inspector in chrome.

Comment: Are these available for windows?

Comment: @JonTaylor are you talking about https://github.com/adobe/brackets ?

Comment: @N30 indeed I am.  Its still in dev stage but even at this point its awesome.

Comment: @refhat Yes available on all platforms (not sure about sublime for linux havent looked yet)